# Why doesn't my query work for a specific parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, rdbms

I have **3** tables

1. **SystemUsers**
2. **Complaints**
3. **Mappings**

**1** is used to register website users.
**2** is for saving complaints

I will discuss **3** later.

When a complaint is received, it is assigned to a system user i.e. AssignToUser_ID in complaints table.

Complaints:

1. CompaintID
2. Date
3. AssignToUser_ID

Now if a user wants to view complaints then only those complaints should be shown which were assigned to a him not other and that is the part I have solved but....

Now I will discuss MAPPING table.

Mapping:

1. MappingID
2. SystemUser_ID
3. AssignToUser_ID

This table is used to store nominated systemusers i.e. if a complained was assigned to me and I decide to assign it to another user too so he also can view the complaints that were actually assigned to me then it would be possible. 
Now this part I have solved somehow but the problem is that If I login as a nominated user then I can view the complaints that were assigned to actual user but if I login as an original user then I can not view the assigned complaints.

My try:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[usp_getAllMarkedComplaints] 
(


    @SystemUser_ID int

)
AS 
Begin

if exists (Select * from mapping where systemuser_id = @SystemUser_ID )
begin
        Select  * From dbo.Complaints Comp
        Where (Comp.AssignToUser_ID IN (select assigntouser_id from mapping where systemuser_id = @SystemUser_ID))      AND 
        Comp.ComplaintStatus_ID <3 
    end
    else
    begin

        Select * From dbo.Complaints Comp
        Where (Comp.AssignToUser_ID = @SystemUser_ID) AND 
        Comp.ComplaintStatus_ID <3 


    end
End
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: I have tried my best to describe the problem and before posting I have spent a lot of time and one should not be so much hardliner and not  everybody is that much perfect to post a good question. Sorry sir but it ain't an essay competition or something. I posted what I felt I should and this is what SOF is for

Comment: I understand the effort,you can look here and see how you can improve the question.https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You use @SystemUser_ID as a systemuser_id AND as a AssignToUser_ID. I think that they are two different notions with their own increments system.
Your AssignToUser_ID n°1 is probably not the same as your systemuser_id n°1.

You need to make two different entries depending on your user type (assigned OR system).

One way to go:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[usp_getAllMarkedComplaints] 
(
    @user_ID int,
    @user_type char(3)
)
AS 
Begin

    if @user_type = 'SYS'
    begin
        Select  * From dbo.Complaints Comp
        Where Comp.AssignToUser_ID IN (select assigntouser_id 
                                        from mapping 
                                        where systemuser_id = @user_ID)
         AND  Comp.ComplaintStatus_ID <3 
    end

    if @user_type = 'ASG'
    begin

        Select * From dbo.Complaints Comp
        Where Comp.AssignToUser_ID = @user_ID
          AND Comp.ComplaintStatus_ID <3 

    end
End
```

Another way to go would be to make two different stored procedure.

Comment: just edited, you will need to change your call too. Sorry, sometimes I put my brain off